# PHP String Differences and Dynamic Restrictions

Tags: php, mysql, match

**Example A [the simplified one]: --------------------------------------------------------------------**

> **MODEL**: String ***{1}*** and keeeeeep on ***{2}*** and oooon...
>
> **CASE_A**: String ***hello*** and keeeeeep on ***two words*** and oooon...
>
> **CASE_B**: String ***anything else*** and keeeeeep on ***just for fun*** and oooon...

I need to get a list with *n* vars called `$v1`, `$v2`, `$vn`... with their respective matched values:
**EDIT**:
Note that the variable names are given depending on the placeholder. Placeholders are always an INT. *(The numbers are just indexes not word count)*
For **case A**:
`$v1`=*hello*
`$v2`=*two words*
`$vn`=*etc*...
For **case B**:
`$v1`=*anything else* 
`$v2`=*just for fun*
`$vn`=*etc*...
As you can see the references to get these values are the "*constant*" parts of both strings.

**Example B [the almost-real one]: --------------------------------------------------------------------**

Now we suppose that each *possible match* is saved in an array *(real case is a long database)*, like this:
**possible_matches**{
[0] *string three* <<<<
[1] *Oneword* <<<<
[2] *Other stuff*
[3] *Harry Poppotter*
[4] *two words* <<<<
[5] *Magic words magic feelings*
}

In the previous example it was not necessary, because each **{n}** "*placeholder*" was separated by "*constant*" strings. But there are cases where these "*placeholders*" are together... so I have to invent a new way to match the **possible matches** (fixed list).

> String ***{1}*** and keeeeeep on ***{2}*** ***{3}*** and oooon...
>
> String ***Oneword*** and keeeeeep on ***two words*** ***string three*** and oooon...

As you can see *(based on the array shown above)*, the result should be:
`$v1`=*hello*
`$v2`=*two words*
`$v3`=*string three*
But how knows PHP how I want my strings ***to be separated***?
**My idea** is doing the next:
1) Get the {2}{3} block as a **single one**.
2) Check in the array if this block *(two words and three words)* is `in_array()`
3) If NOT:
4) Remove the last word of it
5) Check again with the new *(two words and three)*.
6) If NOT:
<<<<
4') Remove the last word of it
5') Check again with the new *(two words and)*.
4'') Remove the last word of it
5'') Check again with the new *(two words)*.
<<<<
7) Repeat 4 and 5 till it is one **possible match** (`in_array()`)
8) The matched one will be **{2}** and the rest of the string will be **{3}**
**My question**: how can I make this, in PHP?
I tried to explain it the most simplified I could, and I hope you understand what I am trying to ask for. If anyone needs more examples I will write them down, just let me know. Thanks for reading.
**EDIT --------------------------------------------------------------------**
A real example:
Array: **possible_matches**{
[0] *Christopher Johnson*
[1] *McCandless*
[2] *cinema*
[3] *tomorrow at night*
}

> **MODEL**: My name is ***{1}*** ***{2}***, and I am going to the ***{3}{4}***
>
> **CASE**: My name is ***Christopher Johnson*** ***McCandless***, and I am going to the ***cinema tomorrow at night***

**Desired** result:
`$v1`=*Christopher Johnson*
`$v2`=*McCandless*
`$v3`=*cinema*
`$v4`=*tomorrow at night*
**Create possible combinations array**

```
function get_possible_groups($string_of_words, $groups_count){
$words=explode(' ',$string_of_words);
$total=count($words);
$group_1=array(array());
$group_2=array(array());
//We can create TOTAL-1 combinations
for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){
$lim=$total-$i-1;
    for($j=0;$j<$total;$j++){
        if($j<$lim){
            $group_1[$i][]=$words[$j];
        }else{
            $group_2[$i][]=$words[$j];
        }
    }
}
return array($group_1,$group_2);
}
```

**UPDATE referenced in comments for the *ACCEPTED* answer**

```
$model="Damn you {1}, {2} will kill you. {3}{4}{5}";
//Array => Save how many single placeholders are in each "placeholder block"
$placeholder_count{
[0]=1, //first block contains one placeholder
[1]=1, //second block contains one placeholder
[2]=3  //third block contains three placeholders
}
//Simplify all blocks into ONE SINGLE regex placeholder
$pattern="/Damn you (.*), (.*) will kill you. (.*)/";

//Match in string
$string="Damn you Spar, Will will kill you. I Love it man.";
preg_match($pattern,$string,$matches);

//View in array which placeholders have to be checked
$block_0=$matches[1]; //Array shows it was 1 p.holder. No check needed
$block_1=$matches[2]; //Array shows it was 1 p.holder. No check needed
$block_2=$matches[3]; //It shows it were 3 p.holders. Possible grouping (n=3)

//Result
$v1=$matches[1];
$v2=$matches[2];

$v3,$v4,$v5=(Result of grouping and querying the $matches[3] with groups_count=3)
```

Comment: How do you know what to look for?

Comment: @DoSparKot I look for those "possible_matches" strings, which are mixed up in a larger string. These strings have a model pattern like in the example. The references are all those constant parts in my string. I made them bold in the example. Each "possible_match" IS in saved in an array (originally in a large database), also shown as an example in the question. Thanks :)

Comment: @DoSparKot I updated the question to show you a more detailed example

Comment: OK, `{1}, {2}` are placeholders which can contain exact word count as it says in placeholder. How many such Models do have to process for a give random string?

Comment: @DoSparKot hmmm... not really. They are placeholders containing the future variable name. In some other models, these placeholders numbers could have another order, but to show a simple example, I put them in ascendent order. The number of words for each placeholder is random (it's a string... don't minding how many words it's composed of). [I updated it again]

Comment: OK, the numbers are just indexes not word count. Can you give actual example not one of your own?

Comment: @DoSparKot I updated it again _(new example at bottom of question)_

Comment: that's better, `possible_matches` array could've had more than two elements right? Why was `and three words` discarded? because `and three words` was not in `possible_matches` array?

Comment: oh, you deleted those parts. That means all words are significant & none of them can be discarded, right?

Comment: @DoSparKot Yeap. Mmm... **possible matches** is a large array with the **expected matches**. It helps in cases where placeholders are together, in order to separate the matches in the correct way (into two **expected matches**). In my last example, the FULL NAME was not expected, but the _NAME_ (Cristopher Johnson) and the _SURNAME_ (McCandless) as separated ones. The array helps me to decide where to separate/split up the string when two placeholders are together :)

Comment: Then add more `possible matches` to last example for more clarity. That last example is more clearer than your made up ones in the initial post. Do you get it?

Comment: @DoSparKot It's true :) I am going to edit the initial example. To make it a bit clearer I added other two `possible matches` to my last example. Thanks for trying to understand my mess.

Comment: we're getting closer. Is `possible matches` a sorted array? what did you do man. In `real example` why `possible matches` has exact count as `desired result`?

Comment: @DoSparKot `possible matches` is not sorted. I put an array to simulate the result of a search into a database. In real working the database contains all possible matches for all possible models (it might be over two-hundred results). I updated my question at the **"real-example"** part (new array) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `Christopher Johnson McCandless` is mapped to `{1}{2}`:

possible combination for forming two groups is:

- **`Christopher Johnson`**  and   **`McCandless`**
- **`Christopher`** and **`Johnson McCandless`**

when `cinema tomorrow at night` is mapped to `{3}{4}`

possible combination for forming two groups is:

- **`cinema`**  and   **`tomorrow at night`**
- **`cinema tomorrow`** and **`at night`**
- **`cinema tomorrow at`** and **`night`**

Write a PHP function to
`get_possible_groups($string_of_words, $group_count)` returns array of array of group combinations.

and an SQL statement like:

```
SELECT count(*), 'cinema' firstWordGroup, 'tomorrow at night' secondWordGroup
  FROM possibleMatchTable
 WHERE possible_match IN ('cinema', 'tomorrow at night')
UNION
SELECT count(*), 'cinema tomorrow', 'at night'
  FROM possibleMatchTable
 WHERE possible_match IN ('cinema tomorrow', 'at night')
UNION
SELECT count(*), 'cinema tomorrow at', 'night'
  FROM possibleMatchTable
 WHERE possible_match IN ('cinema tomorrow at', 'night');
```

one possible output can be:

```
+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
| count(*) | firstWordGroup     | secondWordGroup   |
+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
|        2 | cinema             | tomorrow at night |
|        0 | cinema tomorrow    | at night          |
|        0 | cinema tomorrow at | night             |
+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

whichever has count 2(two word groups) that's your answer.

If `MODEL` text is a `fulltext` indexed column then for any given random string you can get most relevant model like:

```
SELECT * FROM model_strings 
WHERE MATCH(model) AGAINST ('Damn you Spar, Kot will kill you.');
```

query might return you something like:

```
+----------------------------------+
| model                            |
+----------------------------------+
| Damn you {1}, {2} will kill you. |
+----------------------------------+
```

Extracting the words for random string using placeholders from `Model`:

```
<?php 

$placeholder_pRegEx = '#\{\d+\}#';

$model = 'Damn you {1}, {2} will kill you. {3}{4}{5}';
$string = 'Damn you Spar, Will will kill you. I Love it man.';

$model_words = explode(' ', $model);
$string_words = explode(' ', $string);

$placeholder_words = array();

for ($idx =0, $jdx=0; $idx < count($string_words); $idx ++) {

    if ($jdx < count($model_words)) {
        if (strcmp($string_words[$idx], $model_words[$jdx])) {
            $placeholder_words[] = $string_words[$idx];

            //Move to next word in Model only if it's a placeholder
            if (preg_match($placeholder_pRegEx, $model_words[$jdx]))
                $jdx++;

        } else
            $jdx++; //they match so move to next word
    } else
        $placeholder_words[] = $string_words[$idx];
}

//Even status will have the count
$status = preg_match_all ($placeholder_pRegEx, $model, $placeholders);

$group_count = count($placeholders[0]);

var_dump(get_defined_vars());
?>
```

Above code will get you values like:

```
'placeholder_words' => array (size=6)
  0 => string 'Spar,' (length=5)
  1 => string 'Will' (length=4)
  2 => string 'I' (length=1)
  3 => string 'Love' (length=4)
  4 => string 'it' (length=2)
  5 => string 'man.' (length=4)

'placeholders' => array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '{1}' (length=3)
      1 => string '{2}' (length=3)
      2 => string '{3}' (length=3)
      3 => string '{4}' (length=3)
      4 => string '{5}' (length=3)

'group_count' => int 5
```

- from there you can call `get possible groupings`
- then SQL query to check against allowed possible matches
- actual words in required groupings.

Alas, it's some question, eh!

Comment: I will have to read about binary search. Apart of this. How could I get the groups? I mean, how could I make the matches to assign each group to its placeholder?. Then, I think for the oher part, separating double_possible_matches, I think it would be better making a query to the database for each step (first remove the last word, then again... and so on, until it gives a true result).

Comment: Got your function; make it generic, it should return array of arrays.

Comment: It'll be harder when you get 3 or more placeholders together. Say like `{7}{8}{9}{10}..{n}` next to each other. If you got that generic php `get_possible_groups()` right then it's easy. Hope you've indexes on this `possible_matches` column.

Comment: So, PHP code is updated and working. Have to make it generic for any number of groups (now it's working for two). Why do you mean it will be easier with this function?. Yeap there are indexes ;) (I re-edited your answer)

Comment: Can you add that function in your question. or you can post an answer too with that function. Reviewers reject your modifications to my post most of the time.

Comment: Coz, if you have that function, possible combinations are ready => query is ready => straight answer with single SQL query.

Comment: So I updated my own question, and added the PHP function at the end. So far I think it is everything almost fixed-up. How can I get the different groups? I mean, how can I assign each possible_matches to each placeholder? Then I should check if there is some "multiplaceholder", and do this process before making the definitive group.

Comment: If there are more than single word in a `placeholder` then it's a candidate for `multiplaceholder`.

Comment: Are there any chances of getting more than two placeholders together like `{6}{7}{8}` in your project? Or two is maximum?

Comment: Hmm... yeah this part I understand it but... I mean, how can I do the first step, the most basic? It is the one at **Example A** => Get the whole list... I do not know how to resolve Example A problem. I think not preg_match nor match_all. It might need a self-made function, isn't it?

Comment: I would say there is no guarantee of getting always two as maximum, so I would say yes: there is a chance of getting three or even more.

Comment: that `MODEL` was just for example wasn't it? they are not stored anywhere. So, for any given string you want to locate `Possible_matches` in them?

Comment: Im afraid that the model is saved too. The models are indexed with FULLTEXT index. But there is no problem because the models come out and THEN I do the get_possible_matches process. So, we could consider that it is like you said: "Any given string"

Comment: Now you've a generic function [Possible grouping of words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144811/possible-grouping-of-words)

Comment: WOW! Thank you a million of lots for asking. I asked too :S (no problem, reviewers might fix it up). I am going to accept your question because you dedicated so much time on my question. Could you still help me on the last problem? _(solving example A => Assign matches to their placeholders)_

Comment: updated post to get relevant model from any given random string.

Comment: Wait, I see unnecessary grouping checks, like `Spar` & `Will` always mapped to `{1}` & `{2}` respectively in program example I added in the end.

Comment: WOW!, Awesome! It took me a time to get documented about the functions you use and understand how they are working. As you say in your last comment, I think doing it this way would make the grouping checks be compulsory. What do you think about using a regex? I could take the model and simplify all multiple placeholders into a single one, and keep the real ones referenced in an array. Then, after matching each placeholder, undo the simplification and make the check only with those which were multiple ones.

Comment: I updated my question with the script I am suggesting in my previous comment. What do you think about it? Do you think it works slower/faster? _(The script is at the very bottom of the question)_