# Matching substrings with placeholders

Tags: php, substring, match

**Definition**:
I came across this scenario while working on [PHP string Differences with Dynamic restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141928/php-string-differences-and-dynamic-restrictions). It might be a reference to understand better what I want.

**Problem**:
Suppose I have a **main** string:

> *"This is a **{1}** string with **{2}** placeholders"*

And a **secondary** one:

> *"This is a **very similar** string with **data for the** placeholders"*

**Question**:
How could I get one variable for each placeholder, called `$v1`, `$v2`, `$vn`, whose values are **"very similar"** and **"data for the"**, respectively? As you can see I need to assign to each placeholder the substring which is not in the main one.

**Notes**:
I am working with *PHP*.

Comment: use `$strRegEx = '#'.preg_replace('#\{\d+\}#', '(.*)', $mainStr).'#';` to get the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use regex to do something like this:

```
$pattern="/This is a (.*) string with (.*) placeholders/";
$subject="This is a very similar string with data for the placeholders";

preg_match($pattern,$subject,$matches);

$v1=$matches[1];
$v2=$matches[2];
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php for more info on regex in php.

Comment: So, if using regex is the unique way, I should create patterns dynamically, because **"main strings"** are dynamic. Do you think there is another option, without using regex?

Comment: @MarkTower You could possibly calculate the length of the part of the string up to the `{0}` and use substrings, but I would think regex would be easier. What part of regex isn't working for you? You should be able to build the regex strings dynamically. Instead of `{0}` put `(.*)`.

Comment: Thanks :) I did not want to use regex because I thought they are slow, but it seems to be the best solution here.

Comment: @MarkTower I understand your concern about the speed. While regex can take a long time when processing a large amount of text (try running regex on thousands of lines - it takes a few minutes), for something that small, I don't think there should be an issue with the speed. I'm glad that this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) maybe?

```
$string = 'This is a %s string with %s placeholders';
$v1 = 'very similar';
$v2 = 'data for the';

$result = sprintf($string, $v1, $v2);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but initially I do not know which are the values for `$v1` and `$v2`... these are the variables I am trying to give the value to :)